# How do I upload to Remini in bulk?

Tags: python, automation, artificial-intelligence, auto, bulk

So, I have to enhance a thousand of different images with the Remini app on Android.

I tried manually processing the images, but it took me like 30 seconds and a lot of energy for each one. What's the problem is that I always need to choose a different image from the gallery and then wait until it gets enhanced, and then I can save it to my gallery. Remini unfortunately doesn't let you upload the images in bulk.

How can I automate the processing of the images?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably cobble something together with a test engine.

https://bitbar.com/blog/top-5-android-testing-frameworks-with-examples/