# How do I get started automating my workflow for enhancing and editing photos using Remini web app and photoshop?

Tags: workflow, photoshop, image-editing

I have hundreds of photos from the 70s-90s that I need to edit.  I've left it for years because it is so labor intensive.  I want to get it done.  I have limited experience with DIY artificial pancreas systems as well as home automation systems like hubitat and am not afraid of a command prompt, but don't know how to start learning more to accomplish my current objectives.

Photos are stored in folders labeled by the year in which they were taken on my Mac desktop (latest OS).  The photos go up by one integer each time.  I need to automate the following:

- Tell remini web app to upload the photo and enhance it (this usually takes 30 seconds to accomplish)
- Save the finished photo (Remini automatically leaves the original name and adds remini enhanced to the end, so I don't need to worry about changing the names)

Rinse and repeat.

For Photoshop:

- Open the photo from a specified folder, open the neural filters and apply the colorize option.
- Save the photo as the same name it currently has plus put "photoshop edit" at the end.

Rinse and repeat.

After this completes, I will review the photos by hand and remove any that didn't work out.  But being able to free up my time from clicking would help speed the process up.

Is this a possibility?  How do I get started?  Thank you!

I have been searching for information to help me get started but am concerned about the website thinking I am a bot if I do this.

Comment: For Photoshop check out the [Script Listener](https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/photoshop/kb/downloadable-plugins-and-content.html) which will record things in Photoshop like a macro. Failing that you could write a simple Photoshop script will will process the image and then save it under a different name.

Comment: @GhoulFool Thanks!  It sent me down the right path, although it ultimately ended up being easier than I expected.  If anyone else searches this in the future - the best way is to create an action that records you clicking "Neural Filters". Followed by "Colorize". Stop recording. Then, go to Files - Scripts - Image Processing, set your parameters and tell it to use the action you just created.  ~ 7 minutes for 92 photos on my ancient Mac.  I will still need to review and cull ones that don't look good, but this is a huge enhancement.  Now if only I can learn python and automate remini.

Comment: Recording actions are good - with the script listener you can effectively make the macro dynamic. You might want to take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70229018/how-do-i-upload-to-remini-in-bulk)